# Jquery/javascript check if the div finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a facebook like button on my website like that:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx"
             data-send="false" data-width="300" 
             data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery or java script to check if this div is 100% finished loading on the page and then do other stuff.

I used `$(document).ready` and `.load` to check but non of them worked (they do the function even before the div finished loading). Does this problem have to do anything with the fact that this div contain an iframe from another website ?
what am I doing wrong here ?

**UPDATE** I just tried this and it did not work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fb-like").load(function (){
         alert("Loaded :)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the issue is that you need to test if the iframe is loaded rather than the div. I would suggest changing your selector to include the child iframe and checking for the load event on this.

```
$('.fb-like iframe').load(function() {
  console.log('iframe loaded');
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened :(, are you sure of your selector ?

Comment: Silly me, forgot the `.`! Try now

Comment: I already did, still :(. I updated my question, please check it out.

Comment: @MaxPain I tested this and seemed to work for me. In you edit it doesnt have the iframe, have you added that in? -> http://tinkerbin.com/2V9CNU7d

Comment: it did work. but I also tried the same code on my website and did not work :(

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.fb-like iframe').on(function() {
  console.log('iframe loaded');
 });
```

Comment: console.log works on any browser that has a console, including IE9, Chrome, Firefox (with Firebug). Probably others but not entirely sure.

Comment: You don't pass any event name to the `on` function, so this wouldn't do anything.